# How to add select in a group by SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

**Table**: I have a database table mytable1 in SQL Server 2012. Table definition is

```
Column_name Type        Length  Nullable
ts          datetime    8       no  
s_no        int         4       no  
calls       int         4       yes
```

**DDL**: And created it using

```
CREATE TABLE mytable1(
   ts DATETIME NOT NULL,
   s_no INT NOT NULL,
   calls  INT
);
```

**Populate data**

```
INSERT INTO mytable1 (ts, s_no, calls)
VALUES
('2016-10-14 10:04:01.000', 3, 56),
('2016-10-14 10:04:01.000', 4, 145),
('2016-10-14 10:09:00.000', 3, 143),
('2016-10-14 10:09:00.000', 4, 329),
('2016-10-14 10:14:01.000', 3, 0),
('2016-10-14 10:14:01.000', 4, 49),
('2016-10-14 10:19:00.000', 3, 6),
('2016-10-14 10:19:00.000', 4, 16),
('2016-10-14 10:24:01.000', 3, 22),
('2016-10-14 10:24:01.000', 4, 28),
('2016-10-14 10:29:00.000', 3, 4),
('2016-10-14 10:29:00.000', 4, 7),
('2016-10-14 10:34:00.000', 3, 14),
('2016-10-14 10:34:00.000', 4, 9),
('2016-10-14 10:38:59.000', 3, 39),
('2016-10-14 10:38:59.000', 4, 391),
('2016-10-14 10:44:01.000', 3, 3),
('2016-10-14 10:44:01.000', 4, 31),
('2016-10-14 10:49:01.000', 3, 116),
('2016-10-14 10:49:01.000', 4, 52),
('2016-10-14 10:54:00.000', 3, 75),
('2016-10-14 10:54:00.000', 4, 8),
('2016-10-14 10:59:00.000', 3, 16),
('2016-10-14 10:59:00.000', 4, 8),
('2016-10-14 11:04:01.000', 3, 23),
('2016-10-14 11:04:01.000', 4, 13);
```

I am trying to divide timestamp into 30 minute window and then select hisghest timestamp from each 30 minute window. Also I want to select all the different s_no values for the highest of 30 minute timestamp.

**Existing Query**: I have a query that does this

```
select m.s_no, m.bucket_window, max(m.ts) ts
from (
    select m.*, datepart(hour, m.ts)*2 + floor(datepart(minute, m.ts)/30) bucket_window
    from mytable1 m
    where m.ts >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
) m
group by m.s_no, m.bucket_window;
```

**Result**: It gives result as

```
s_no    bucket_window   ts
3       20              2016-10-14 10:29:00.000
4       20              2016-10-14 10:29:00.000
3       21              2016-10-14 10:59:00.000
4       21              2016-10-14 10:59:00.000
3       22              2016-10-14 11:04:01.000
4       22              2016-10-14 11:04:01.000
```

Now I want to improve this query and add column *calls* in the above result. This column should have value from *calls* column of the *mytable1* table where the combination of *s_no* and *ts* from above result matches with combination of *s_no* and *ts* from *mytable1* table.

**Expected Result**: So result I want now is

```
s_no    bucket_window   ts                          calls
3       20              2016-10-14 10:29:00.000     4
4       20              2016-10-14 10:29:00.000     7
3       21              2016-10-14 10:59:00.000     16
4       21              2016-10-14 10:59:00.000     8
3       22              2016-10-14 11:04:01.000     23
4       22              2016-10-14 11:04:01.000     13
```

I tried using join but can't put the query together with correct syntax:

**What I tried:**

```
select m.s_no, m.bucket_window, max(m.ts) ts, i.calls
from (
    select m.*, datepart(hour, m.ts)*2 + floor(datepart(minute, m.ts)/30) bucket_window
    from mytable1 m
    where m.ts >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
) m
LEFT JOIN mytable1 i
ON max(m.ts) = i.ts--OR (m.ts) = i.ts
group by m.s_no, m.bucket_window, i.calls
```

Please suggest me how I can modify this existing query to get the expected result.

As this existing query is being used in production for long time and is used as sub query in other dynamically generated queries, I don't want to change   it entirely to get expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT M1.*,
(SELECT calls From mytable1 M2 where M2.ts=M1.ts and M2.s_no=M1.s_no) as calls
FROM
(
    select m.s_no, m.bucket_window, max(m.ts) ts
    from (
        select m.*, datepart(hour, m.ts)*2 + floor(datepart(minute, m.ts)/30) bucket_window
        from mytable1 m
        where m.ts >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    ) m
    group by m.s_no, m.bucket_window
) M1
```

Comment: I used your answer for the simplicity as it was easier for me to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me see if this can help you:

```
select s_no, bucket_window, ts, c as calls from (
  select s_no, ts, bucket_window,
         max(ts) over (partition by s_no, bucket_window) maxts,     
         case 
           when ts=max(ts) over (partition by s_no, bucket_window) 
             then calls 
          end c 

          from (
                select m.*, 
                      datepart(hour, m.ts)*2 + floor(datepart(minute, m.ts)/30) bucket_window
                  from mytable1 m
                 where m.ts >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                     ) x  
          ) y    
   where  ts=maxts;
```

I started by your initial query, but tried to do without having to join mytable1 again. I don't know SQL Server syntax, but I tested it on rextester and it says it should work.

Here it is the example I prepared on [rextester](http://rextester.com/SJAT12311): I put all the three available solution and they all seem to give the answer you asked for.

As I don't know SQL Server syntax, I have used SQL standard analytical function that I might have used also on Teradata or Oracle to modify your query.

Comment: It doesn't give any syntax error but somehow, doesn't pull any row in result.

Comment: My bad, it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use top(1) with ties .. order by row_number()

```
select top(1) with ties m.s_no, datepart(hour, m.ts)*2 + floor(datepart(minute, m.ts)/30) bucket_window, ts, calls
from mytable1 m
where m.ts >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
order by row_number() over (partition by m.s_no, datepart(hour, m.ts)*2 + floor(datepart(minute, m.ts)/30) 
           order by ts desc);
```